# Bode Phase Plot

Tags: trigonometry, matlab, control-theory, linear-control

I have a simple transfer function, given by:

$$
 \text T(j\omega)=2\cdot(1-2\text{j}\cdot\omega)
$$
I'm attempting to make it's **Bode Phase plot** without any calculator or program.

What i did:

$$
\text{Argument}T(j\omega)=\text{Argument}(2)
+ \text{Argument}(1-2\text{j}\cdot\omega)
$$

$$
\text{Argument}T(j\omega)= \text{Atan}(\frac{0}{2})+\text{Atan}(\frac{2\cdot\omega}{1})+\pi 
$$

When $$\omega= 0 \Rightarrow \text{Argument}T(j\omega)=\pi  $$

When $$\omega= infinity \Rightarrow \text{Argument}T(j\omega)=\frac{3\pi }{2}
 $$

Here is the solution in Matlab. Can some explain me how to use my calculations to obtain the same plot?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Probably,
$$\angle(1-2\omega \mathrm{j}) = -\operatorname{atan}\left(\frac{2\omega}{1}\right) \ne \operatorname{atan}\left(\frac{2\omega}{1}\right) + \pi.$$